# Merge two different tables with Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I’d would like to merge two different tables with similar and different columns. The only different columns are : Amount-F21 and Amount A-21.  My issue is when I write the SQL request (UNION ALL)  with Access, it deletes the column Amount A-21 but I need this one though. Thanks.

```
SELECT * FROM [Source Alloc-A21]
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM [Source Alloc-F21]
```

Comment: It doesn't (can't) delete anything, but a field can have only one name and that is picked from the first query. Replace the tables with simple select queries where you assign the same alias for the two different field names.

Comment: pls, take a picture of the results to see the problems through the results.

Comment: This will only run if there are equal numbers of columns in each data-set, and that the data-types are compatible *(with implicit data-type coercion where necessary)*.  Then, the column names are inherited from the first `SELECT` ***only***.  The data from subsequent `SELECT` are allocated by the column position ***not*** the name.  So, if you have `SELECT a, b, F21 ...  UNION ALL SELECT a, b, A21` the data from `A21` is ***not*** deleted, it just appears in the `F21` column.  If you want to over-ride that, simply avoid using `*` *(which is bad practice in production code anyway)*.

Answer (score 1):

To use the star notation `Table.*` with `UNION`, the columns in both tables must be equal. If they are not, you need to select individual columns and provide default values for the columns that are missing for both tables.

For example:

```
SELECT TableA.A, TableA.B, TableA.[Amount-F21], 0 AS [Amount-A21]
FROM TableA
UNION ALL
SELECT TableB.A, TableB.B, 0 AS [Amount-F21], TableB.[Amount-A21]
FROM TableB
```

This will report 0 for any of the missing columns (Amount-F21 or Amount A-21).

You can then sum the results to hide the *zero* (default) values.

```
SELECT T.A, T.B, SUM(T.[Amount-F21]) AS [Amount-F21], SUM(T.[Amount-A21]) AS [Amount-A21]
FROM (
      SELECT TableA.A, TableA.B, TableA.[Amount-F21], 0 AS [Amount-A21]
      FROM TableA
      UNION ALL
      SELECT TableB.A, TableB.B, 0 AS [Amount-F21], TableB.[Amount-A21]
      FROM TableB
) AS T
GROUP BY T.A, T.B
```

Comment: Also, note that if the schema changes *(adding columns, re-ordering columns, etc)*, this still works.  Using `*`, however, leads to code that is fragile to schema changes.  As a general rule, using `*` in production code is bad practice; always be explicit, like in this answer.

Comment: @MatBailie I wasn't aware that re-ordering the columns would still work. Thanks for that.

Comment: `*` orders the columns according to how they appear in the schema.  By enumerating exactly which columns you want, in the order you want them, your answer doesn't care or depend on the order they appear in the schema.